# Python: Convert 2d point cloud to grayscale image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, point-clouds

I have an array of variable length filled with 2d coordinate points (coming from a point cloud) which are distributed around (0,0) and i want to convert them into a 2d matrix (=grayscale image).

```
# have
array = [(1.0,1.1),(0.0,0.0),...]
# want
matrix = [[0,100,...],[255,255,...],...]
```

how would i achieve this using python and numpy

Comment: point clouds are coordinate numbers. Grey scale images are intensity values. How do you intend to convert a coordinate to an intensity value? what is the mapping?

Comment: if many points "land" in the same grid (pixel) then the intensity would increase.

Comment: still the mapping to intensity is arbitrary unless you provide one. Seems like the problem is resolved anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d` is what you are looking for.

It basically bins your data into 2-dimensional bins (with a size of your choice).
[here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) the documentation and a working example is given below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [np.random.randn(1000), np.random.randn(1000)]
plt.scatter(data[0], data[1])
```

[image]

Then you can call `hist2d` on your data, for instance like this

```
plt.hist2d(data[0], data[1], bins=20)
```

[image]

note that the arguments of `hist2d` are two 1-dimensional arrays, so you will have to do a bit of reshaping of our data prior to feed it to `hist2d`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution using only numpy without the need for matplotlib and therefor plots:

```
import numpy as np
# given a 2dArray "array" and a desired image shape "[x,y]"
matrix = np.histogram2d(array[:,0], array[:,1], bins=[x,y])
```

Comment: If you have intensity values (`I`) along with x and y coordinates, you can use `matrix = np.histogram2d(array[:,0], array[:,1], bins=[x,y], weights=I)`. You can also consider setting `normed=False` to sum up the intensity values.